# Asp.Net Core 3.0 MVC Identity Adding Role Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I am trying to add identity role for my ASP.NET project. When I am add `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>();` under `Configure` method it is not working.

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDbContext<UserAuthContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("UserAuthContextConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<YNYWebSiteUser>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserAuthContext>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();
        });
    }
}
```

Without `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>();` code, project is working well with user authentication. But when I am add this line then project give me exception like:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[YNYWebSite.Areas.Identity.Data.YNYWebSiteUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter<TContainerBuilder>.CreateServiceProvider(object containerBuilder)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
YNYWebSite.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs
-
namespace YNYWebSite
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
```

What should I do for this issue?

Comment: Show the code for your `UserAuthContext` please

Comment: @crgolden I added code as answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use roles, you need to add them to your `UserAuthContext`. For example:

```cs
public class UserAuthContext : IdentityDbContext<YNYWebSiteUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    ⋮
}
```

Reference: [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model#model-generic-types)

**UPDATE:**

Try using `AddIdentity` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity`:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<YNYWebSiteUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserAuthContext>();
```

Comment: I added `IdentityRole` and `string` parameters but still not working. It's giving same exception.

Answer (score 0):

@crgolden there is the `UserAuthContext` code:

```
namespace YNYWebSite.Data
{
    public class UserAuthContext : IdentityDbContext<YNYWebSiteUser>
    {
        public UserAuthContext(DbContextOptions<UserAuthContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```